# svg defined with same width and height, same viewport yet they are different size

Tags: html, css, xml, svg, viewport

I'm trying to have 3 icons of social media as SVG in a flex container.

I defined for each SVG the same height, width and viewport.

The facebook and instagram svg are same size , but the twitter one is a different size yet the viewport width and height which i defined in the svg tag are the same

So i'm trying to have all those social media icons in the same parent container and all have the same size.

```css
.social-media {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 25px;
}

.social-media svg {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="social-media">
    <div class="twitter">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 112.196 112.196" style="enable-background:new 0 0 112.196 112.196;" xml:space="preserve" width="260px" height="260px">
            <path fill="#03a9f4" d="M24,4C13,4,4,13,4,24s9,20,20,20s20-9,20-20S35,4,24,4z" />
            <path fill="#fff" d="M36,17.1c-0.9,0.4-2,0.8-3,0.9c1-0.6,2.6-1.9,3-3c-1,0.6-2.7,1.2-3.8,1.4C31.3,15.4,30,15,28.6,15 c-2.7,0-4.6,2.3-4.6,5v2c-4,0-7.9-3-10.3-6c-0.4,0.7-0.7,1.6-0.7,2.5c0,1.8,1.7,3.7,3,4.5c-0.8,0-2.3-0.6-3-1c0,0,0,0,0,0.1 c0,2.4,1.7,4,3.9,4.4C16.5,26.6,16,27,14.1,27c0.6,1.9,3.8,3,5.9,3c-1.7,1.3-4.7,2-7,2c-0.4,0-0.6,0-1,0c2.2,1.4,5.2,2,8,2  c9.1,0,14-6.9,14-13.4c0-0.2,0-0.9,0-1.1C35,18.8,35.3,18.1,36,17.1" />
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="facebook">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 112.196 112.196" style="enable-background:new 0 0 112.196 112.196;" xml:space="preserve" width="260px" height="260px">
            <g>
                <circle style="fill:#3B5998;" cx="56.098" cy="56.098" r="56.098" />
                <path style="fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M70.201,58.294h-10.01v36.672H45.025V58.294h-7.213V45.406h7.213v-8.34
          c0-5.964,2.833-15.303,15.301-15.303L71.56,21.81v12.51h-8.151c-1.337,0-3.217,0.668-3.217,3.513v7.585h11.334L70.201,58.294z" />
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="instagram">
        <svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 112.196 112.196" width="260px" height="260px" style="enable-background:new 0 0 112.196 112.196;" xml:space="preserve">
            <g>
                <circle id="XMLID_115_" style="fill:#6A453B;" cx="56.098" cy="56.097" r="56.098" />
                <path style="fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M79.124,22.506h-46.05c-5.83,0-10.56,4.73-10.56,10.57v46.05c0,5.83,4.73,10.56,10.56,10.56h46.05
          c5.83,0,10.56-4.73,10.56-10.56v-46.05C89.684,27.236,84.954,22.506,79.124,22.506z M71.983,30.276l8.44-0.02h0.02
          c0.81-0.01,1.47,0.65,1.47,1.45v8.47c0,0.81-0.65,1.46-1.46,1.46l-8.43,0.03c-0.81,0-1.46-0.65-1.46-1.45l-0.03-8.47
          C70.523,30.936,71.173,30.286,71.983,30.276z M45.804,50.326c0.22-0.38,0.45-0.76,0.71-1.12c2.15-2.98,5.64-4.93,9.58-4.93
          c3.95,0,7.44,1.95,9.59,4.93c0.26,0.36,0.49,0.74,0.71,1.13c0.96,1.7,1.53,3.67,1.53,5.76c0,6.52-5.31,11.82-11.83,11.82
          c-6.52,0-11.82-5.3-11.82-11.82C44.273,54.006,44.834,52.036,45.804,50.326z M83.144,76.706c0,3.55-2.89,6.44-6.44,6.44h-41.21
          c-3.55,0-6.44-2.89-6.44-6.44v-27.5h10.03c-0.25,0.61-0.47,1.25-0.65,1.89c-0.46,1.59-0.7,3.27-0.7,5
          c0,10.13,8.24,18.37,18.36,18.37c10.13,0,18.37-8.24,18.37-18.37c0-1.73-0.25-3.41-0.7-5c-0.19-0.64-0.4-1.28-0.65-1.89h10.03
          V76.706z" />
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But they are the same size. You've just drawn in the top left of one of them instead of over the whole canvas. Add background-color:yellow as a style to see for instance.

Comment: Yes I see that each SVG tag are the same size because of the viewport. Yet the content inside the viewport doesn't take the full width and height. Maybe it's because my knowledge of SVG's is limited (i'm not the one who drew them, so i'm not fully understanding the signification of the numbers in the <path>). What i'm trying to achieve is to have each one of them 100% width and height of their viewport

Comment: change the values of the viewBox then.

Comment: How do i know which value to put ?

Comment: Experiment till you get values that work for you.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the icons are drawn in a vector editor with different physical sizes.

To find out these sizes, for example, the twitter icon, you need to use the JS getBBox() method.

```
<script>
 console.log(twitter.getBBox())
</script>
```

```css
.social-media {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 25px;
}

.social-media svg {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.twitter {
border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="social-media">
    <div class="twitter" >
        <svg viewBox="0 0 112.196 112.196" style="enable-background:new 0 0 112.196 112.196;" xml:space="preserve" width="260px" height="260px" >
            <g>
            <path id="twitter" fill="#03a9f4" d="M24,4C13,4,4,13,4,24s9,20,20,20s20-9,20-20S35,4,24,4z" />
            <path  fill="#fff" d="M36,17.1c-0.9,0.4-2,0.8-3,0.9c1-0.6,2.6-1.9,3-3c-1,0.6-2.7,1.2-3.8,1.4C31.3,15.4,30,15,28.6,15 c-2.7,0-4.6,2.3-4.6,5v2c-4,0-7.9-3-10.3-6c-0.4,0.7-0.7,1.6-0.7,2.5c0,1.8,1.7,3.7,3,4.5c-0.8,0-2.3-0.6-3-1c0,0,0,0,0,0.1 c0,2.4,1.7,4,3.9,4.4C16.5,26.6,16,27,14.1,27c0.6,1.9,3.8,3,5.9,3c-1.7,1.3-4.7,2-7,2c-0.4,0-0.6,0-1,0c2.2,1.4,5.2,2,8,2  c9.1,0,14-6.9,14-13.4c0-0.2,0-0.9,0-1.1C35,18.8,35.3,18.1,36,17.1" />
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="facebook">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 112.196 112.196" style="enable-background:new 0 0 112.196 112.196;" xml:space="preserve" width="260px" height="260px">
            <g >
                <circle id="facebook" style="fill:#3B5998;" cx="56.098" cy="56.098" r="56.098" />
                <path style="fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M70.201,58.294h-10.01v36.672H45.025V58.294h-7.213V45.406h7.213v-8.34
          c0-5.964,2.833-15.303,15.301-15.303L71.56,21.81v12.51h-8.151c-1.337,0-3.217,0.668-3.217,3.513v7.585h11.334L70.201,58.294z" />
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="instagram">
        <svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 112.196 112.196" width="260px" height="260px" style="enable-background:new 0 0 112.196 112.196;" xml:space="preserve">
            <g>
                <circle id="instagram" style="fill:#6A453B;" cx="56.098" cy="56.097" r="56.098" />
                <path style="fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M79.124,22.506h-46.05c-5.83,0-10.56,4.73-10.56,10.57v46.05c0,5.83,4.73,10.56,10.56,10.56h46.05
          c5.83,0,10.56-4.73,10.56-10.56v-46.05C89.684,27.236,84.954,22.506,79.124,22.506z M71.983,30.276l8.44-0.02h0.02
          c0.81-0.01,1.47,0.65,1.47,1.45v8.47c0,0.81-0.65,1.46-1.46,1.46l-8.43,0.03c-0.81,0-1.46-0.65-1.46-1.45l-0.03-8.47
          C70.523,30.936,71.173,30.286,71.983,30.276z M45.804,50.326c0.22-0.38,0.45-0.76,0.71-1.12c2.15-2.98,5.64-4.93,9.58-4.93
          c3.95,0,7.44,1.95,9.59,4.93c0.26,0.36,0.49,0.74,0.71,1.13c0.96,1.7,1.53,3.67,1.53,5.76c0,6.52-5.31,11.82-11.83,11.82
          c-6.52,0-11.82-5.3-11.82-11.82C44.273,54.006,44.834,52.036,45.804,50.326z M83.144,76.706c0,3.55-2.89,6.44-6.44,6.44h-41.21
          c-3.55,0-6.44-2.89-6.44-6.44v-27.5h10.03c-0.25,0.61-0.47,1.25-0.65,1.89c-0.46,1.59-0.7,3.27-0.7,5
          c0,10.13,8.24,18.37,18.36,18.37c10.13,0,18.37-8.24,18.37-18.37c0-1.73-0.25-3.41-0.7-5c-0.19-0.64-0.4-1.28-0.65-1.89h10.03
          V76.706z" />
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
 console.log(twitter.getBBox())
</script>
```

The resulting values must be added to the `viewBox="4 4 40 40"` for the twitter icon
And then the empty padding will be cut off from the icon and it will completely fill the parent container.

```css
.social-media {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 25px;
}

.social-media svg {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.twitter {
border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="social-media">
    <div class="twitter" >
        <svg viewBox="4 4 40 40" style="enable-background:new 0 0 112.196 112.196;" xml:space="preserve" width="260px" height="260px" >
            <g>
            <path id="twitter" fill="#03a9f4" d="M24,4C13,4,4,13,4,24s9,20,20,20s20-9,20-20S35,4,24,4z" />
            <path  fill="#fff" d="M36,17.1c-0.9,0.4-2,0.8-3,0.9c1-0.6,2.6-1.9,3-3c-1,0.6-2.7,1.2-3.8,1.4C31.3,15.4,30,15,28.6,15 c-2.7,0-4.6,2.3-4.6,5v2c-4,0-7.9-3-10.3-6c-0.4,0.7-0.7,1.6-0.7,2.5c0,1.8,1.7,3.7,3,4.5c-0.8,0-2.3-0.6-3-1c0,0,0,0,0,0.1 c0,2.4,1.7,4,3.9,4.4C16.5,26.6,16,27,14.1,27c0.6,1.9,3.8,3,5.9,3c-1.7,1.3-4.7,2-7,2c-0.4,0-0.6,0-1,0c2.2,1.4,5.2,2,8,2  c9.1,0,14-6.9,14-13.4c0-0.2,0-0.9,0-1.1C35,18.8,35.3,18.1,36,17.1" />
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="facebook">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 112.196 112.196" style="enable-background:new 0 0 112.196 112.196;" xml:space="preserve" width="260px" height="260px">
            <g >
                <circle id="facebook" style="fill:#3B5998;" cx="56.098" cy="56.098" r="56.098" />
                <path style="fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M70.201,58.294h-10.01v36.672H45.025V58.294h-7.213V45.406h7.213v-8.34
          c0-5.964,2.833-15.303,15.301-15.303L71.56,21.81v12.51h-8.151c-1.337,0-3.217,0.668-3.217,3.513v7.585h11.334L70.201,58.294z" />
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="instagram">
        <svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 112.196 112.196" width="260px" height="260px" style="enable-background:new 0 0 112.196 112.196;" xml:space="preserve">
            <g>
                <circle id="instagram" style="fill:#6A453B;" cx="56.098" cy="56.097" r="56.098" />
                <path style="fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M79.124,22.506h-46.05c-5.83,0-10.56,4.73-10.56,10.57v46.05c0,5.83,4.73,10.56,10.56,10.56h46.05
          c5.83,0,10.56-4.73,10.56-10.56v-46.05C89.684,27.236,84.954,22.506,79.124,22.506z M71.983,30.276l8.44-0.02h0.02
          c0.81-0.01,1.47,0.65,1.47,1.45v8.47c0,0.81-0.65,1.46-1.46,1.46l-8.43,0.03c-0.81,0-1.46-0.65-1.46-1.45l-0.03-8.47
          C70.523,30.936,71.173,30.286,71.983,30.276z M45.804,50.326c0.22-0.38,0.45-0.76,0.71-1.12c2.15-2.98,5.64-4.93,9.58-4.93
          c3.95,0,7.44,1.95,9.59,4.93c0.26,0.36,0.49,0.74,0.71,1.13c0.96,1.7,1.53,3.67,1.53,5.76c0,6.52-5.31,11.82-11.83,11.82
          c-6.52,0-11.82-5.3-11.82-11.82C44.273,54.006,44.834,52.036,45.804,50.326z M83.144,76.706c0,3.55-2.89,6.44-6.44,6.44h-41.21
          c-3.55,0-6.44-2.89-6.44-6.44v-27.5h10.03c-0.25,0.61-0.47,1.25-0.65,1.89c-0.46,1.59-0.7,3.27-0.7,5
          c0,10.13,8.24,18.37,18.36,18.37c10.13,0,18.37-8.24,18.37-18.37c0-1.73-0.25-3.41-0.7-5c-0.19-0.64-0.4-1.28-0.65-1.89h10.03
          V76.706z" />
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you need to reduce the size of icons to `48px` for example, then it will be enough to reduce the size of the user's viewport from `260px` to `48px`

```css
.social-media {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 25px;
}

.social-media svg {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="social-media">
    <div class="twitter" >
        <svg viewBox="4 4 40 40" style="enable-background:new 0 0 112.196 112.196;" xml:space="preserve" width="48" height="48" >
            <g>
            <path id="twitter" fill="#03a9f4" d="M24,4C13,4,4,13,4,24s9,20,20,20s20-9,20-20S35,4,24,4z" />
            <path  fill="#fff" d="M36,17.1c-0.9,0.4-2,0.8-3,0.9c1-0.6,2.6-1.9,3-3c-1,0.6-2.7,1.2-3.8,1.4C31.3,15.4,30,15,28.6,15 c-2.7,0-4.6,2.3-4.6,5v2c-4,0-7.9-3-10.3-6c-0.4,0.7-0.7,1.6-0.7,2.5c0,1.8,1.7,3.7,3,4.5c-0.8,0-2.3-0.6-3-1c0,0,0,0,0,0.1 c0,2.4,1.7,4,3.9,4.4C16.5,26.6,16,27,14.1,27c0.6,1.9,3.8,3,5.9,3c-1.7,1.3-4.7,2-7,2c-0.4,0-0.6,0-1,0c2.2,1.4,5.2,2,8,2  c9.1,0,14-6.9,14-13.4c0-0.2,0-0.9,0-1.1C35,18.8,35.3,18.1,36,17.1" />
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="facebook">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 112.196 112.196" style="enable-background:new 0 0 112.196 112.196;" xml:space="preserve" width="48" height="48">
            <g >
                <circle id="facebook" style="fill:#3B5998;" cx="56.098" cy="56.098" r="56.098" />
                <path style="fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M70.201,58.294h-10.01v36.672H45.025V58.294h-7.213V45.406h7.213v-8.34
          c0-5.964,2.833-15.303,15.301-15.303L71.56,21.81v12.51h-8.151c-1.337,0-3.217,0.668-3.217,3.513v7.585h11.334L70.201,58.294z" />
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="instagram">
        <svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 112.196 112.196" width="48" height="48" style="enable-background:new 0 0 112.196 112.196;" xml:space="preserve">
            <g>
                <circle id="instagram" style="fill:#6A453B;" cx="56.098" cy="56.097" r="56.098" />
                <path style="fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M79.124,22.506h-46.05c-5.83,0-10.56,4.73-10.56,10.57v46.05c0,5.83,4.73,10.56,10.56,10.56h46.05
          c5.83,0,10.56-4.73,10.56-10.56v-46.05C89.684,27.236,84.954,22.506,79.124,22.506z M71.983,30.276l8.44-0.02h0.02
          c0.81-0.01,1.47,0.65,1.47,1.45v8.47c0,0.81-0.65,1.46-1.46,1.46l-8.43,0.03c-0.81,0-1.46-0.65-1.46-1.45l-0.03-8.47
          C70.523,30.936,71.173,30.286,71.983,30.276z M45.804,50.326c0.22-0.38,0.45-0.76,0.71-1.12c2.15-2.98,5.64-4.93,9.58-4.93
          c3.95,0,7.44,1.95,9.59,4.93c0.26,0.36,0.49,0.74,0.71,1.13c0.96,1.7,1.53,3.67,1.53,5.76c0,6.52-5.31,11.82-11.83,11.82
          c-6.52,0-11.82-5.3-11.82-11.82C44.273,54.006,44.834,52.036,45.804,50.326z M83.144,76.706c0,3.55-2.89,6.44-6.44,6.44h-41.21
          c-3.55,0-6.44-2.89-6.44-6.44v-27.5h10.03c-0.25,0.61-0.47,1.25-0.65,1.89c-0.46,1.59-0.7,3.27-0.7,5
          c0,10.13,8.24,18.37,18.36,18.37c10.13,0,18.37-8.24,18.37-18.37c0-1.73-0.25-3.41-0.7-5c-0.19-0.64-0.4-1.28-0.65-1.89h10.03
          V76.706z" />
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT :
I manage to find a fix (more like a hack I guess) to have the same size, I think it is not the best way to do it, but if someone ever has the same problem as me you can do as following :

1- Replace the first path tag of the twitter SVG by a circle tag (to match the 2 others SVG)

```html
<circle style="fill:#03a9f4;" cx="56.098" cy="56.098" r="56.098"></circle>
```

Instead of :

```html
<path fill="#03a9f4" d="M24,4C13,4,4,13,4,24s9,20,20,20s20-9,20-20S35,4,24,4z" />
```

2- Add some CSS style to the Path of the twitter icon

```css
transform: translate(85%, 85%) scale(3);
transform-origin: center;
```

Like I said, what I did is more of a hack and i'm certain there is a way more proper way to do it, If anyone has the answer I would be glad to hear about it